# Fail to validate issuer signing key for JWT

Tags: c#, jwt

I have an end point which is protected by the `[Authorize]` attribute. I want to allow access to it, when a token is provided that is signed with the phrase "Super-Secret-Key" For now, I just generate the token with [Jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) (you can see a screenshot at the end of the post). However, when I visit the end point, just get a **401 Unauthorized**, even if I send the encoded token along as a bearer token (using Postman).

What am I missing?

**Program.cs**

```
var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
    ValidateAudience = false,
    ValidateLifetime = false,
    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Super-Secret-Key"))
};

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
{ 
    builder.Services
        .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(options => options.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters);

    builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
    builder.Services.AddControllers();
}

(...)
```

[image: Screenshot of the token in Jwt.io]

Comment: Hi, have you tried to encode the secret as base 64 (check secret base64 encoded)?

Comment: @ale91 why should he do that? It's a simple string, neither binary nor any special characters.

Comment: Because seems to be required base64 encoded in asp.net core as default, have you tried?

Comment: @ale91 I haven't tried that you, but where do you see that it requires Base64 encoding?

Comment: Sorry, the issue is that asp.net core tries to validate the token issuer by default that you did not set up on jwt.io: try to set `ValidateIssuer = false` inside `TokenValidationParameters`.

Comment: @ale91 that would make sense. But how do you then see the issuer of a token? For instance when I generate one of Jwt.io?

Comment: @JakobBuskSørensen I explained that inside the following answer

Answer (score 0):

the issue is that asp.net core tries to validate the token issuer by default that you did not set up on jwt.io. Set `ValidateIssuer = false` inside `TokenValidationParameters`:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateAudience = false,
                ValidateLifetime = false,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Super-Secret-Key"))
            };
        });
```

If you want to specify an issuer to your JWT token you have to add the **iss** standard claim (Payload data) as specified inside official docs: https://jwt.io/introduction.
Here's an example:
[image: jwt.io issuer]

Validation setup:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateAudience = false,
                ValidateLifetime = false,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                ValidateIssuer = true,     //Validate issuer
                ValidIssuer = "MyIssuer",  //Issuer to validate
                //ValidIssuers = new List<string>() { "MyIssuer", "MySecondIssuer" },  //You can specify multiple issuers
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Super-Secret-Key"))
            };
        });
```

There also are other "standard" (registered) claims that you can use like:

- **exp**: timestamp that identifies the expiration time of the token.
- **nbf**: timestamp that identifies the time before which the JWT
  must not be accepted for processing.
- **aud**: audience identifies recipients that the JWT is
  intended for.
  that you can validate with standard validation options or with custom-written validation logic.

See: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7519#section-4.1

Comment: Awesome. I will try this when I get home from vacation :-)

Comment: I finally got it to work. I did have to use a key of 32 characters though, which I don't really understand. When I wrote a blog post about JWT's a while ago, I used 16 characters and that was enough :-|
https://busk.blog/2022/01/31/authentication-with-jwt-in-net-6/

Comment: @JakobBuskSørensen I think the key length was not the issue, the issue was the `ValidateIssuer` property set to `true` without issuer specified inside the jwt token that you have generated... I err? My example also works with 16 chars key length.

Comment: there was more than one issue with my original code  and your example helped fix most of it. But even with your example, I can't get it to work with an externally generated JWT, unless it's signed with at least 32 characters.

Comment: Ok, very strange, I would like to investigate this.. can you provide more information about your environment? Like .net version, runtime options, ... Thank you

Comment: I pushed it to git, so you can see the details yourself. I'm running it from VS Code with `dotnet run`. 
https://github.com/BuildItBusk/ValidateJwt/blob/main/Program.cs

Comment: Also I can get it to work with a 16 char token for https://jwt.io/ - but not with the same token from https://token.dev/ (despite using HS256 at both).

Comment: Hi, I think that token.dev fills the remaining chars of the key with random/filler chars to reach the length of 256 char as specified in the informations popop: `The HS256 signing algorithm requires a key with a minimum size of 256, found: 0`. If you use random generated key with the length of 256 char and try to generate JWT both in jwt.io and token.dev you get the same result and the authentication works like a charm inside your web api project (same JWT are generated).